# multiples models and one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ado.net

How can we use multiple models in one view to get data from user using ADO.NET as a Database?

Comment: as you are a new comer to Stack Overflow community it is adviced to do a background search on your problem before you ask the question several resources are available like google, also there is no need to introduce yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a quick search on google has provided these results

[Multiple models in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764011/multiple-models-in-a-view)

[Multiple Models in a Single View (C# MVC3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5763631/multiple-model-in-a-single-view-mvc3)

[ASP.NET MVC 3 multiple Models to single Form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6087366/asp-net-mvc-3-multiple-models-to-single-form)

[Two models in one view in ASP MVC 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5550627/two-models-in-one-view-in-asp-mvc-3)